# Why can I not assign a binary literal of 32 bits for a int32?

Tags: c#

Why does the compiler fail with this error: 'Cannot implicitly convert uint to int' when I do this?:

```
int bits = 0b1001_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000;
```

Comment: Because you are trying to store 3000000000 into a variable that can only hold values up to 2000000000. I think you are trying to ask, how do I write a negative int literal without using a - sign?

Comment: Ah... I didn't even calculate the value. That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0b1001_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000` is an `uint` value. What you can do is explictly convert it to `int`, here with [`unchecked`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/unchecked) to allow for negative numbers (when given value exceeds `Int32.MaxValue`):

```cs
int bits = unchecked((int)0b1001_1000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000);
```

In this example you will have `bits == -1744830464`

Comment: thanks! I'm marking as answer because it answer exactly my question. But now I wonder if it's possible to assign a 32 bit binary literal to an int wihout having to explicitly convert ... ?

Comment: Yes, as long as that literal is inferior or equal to `Int32.MaxValue`, _i.e._ the sign bit is `0`. In your example the literal's sign bit is `1`, and can hence not be converted to `int` without doing it explicitly as I did here.